# Play a list of track from table

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

I created a database with a table that contain information about thousands of tracks.
One of these informations is the directory of the track to play when i click "Play".

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata ))
    {
    echo "<tbody><tr><td>";
    echo $row['position'];
    $path = "audio/";
    $track = $path . $row["path"] . ".mp3";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo '<input type="image" src="images/play.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick="play();">';
    echo "<audio id='audio' src=$track></audio>";
    echo '<input type="image" src="images/pause.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick="pause()">';
    echo '<audio id="audio" src=""></audio>';
    echo "</td><td>"; 
etc..
```

The problem is that when I click "Play" in all of different tracks it play only the first track of "audio" folder.
What is the correct method to play different tracks depending on rows?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the Page Source and see what you are actually sending to the browser

Comment: You have multiple audio elements with the same id - that's not correct for a start.

Comment: I saw the source from my browser and the audio src are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
This is the solution:
Delete multiple audio tags and set only one audio tag out of table.
Send the path in the column as parameter to javascript play function and edit audio.src then audio.load and then audio.play.

```
echo '<input type="image" src="images/play.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick="play(\''.$track.'\');">';
```

IMPORTANT: quotes and backslash are important to send a string.

Thank.